# String contains character but strpos() returns false php

Tags: php

```
    $question = "This first Question is “Single Type” and contains data for chemistry1 chapter and Section was CHEMISTRY.
        a. a
        b. a
        c. a
        d. a
        Ans. a";

    $a = 97; // ASCII Code for a
    $search = chr($a).".";

    if(strpos(trim($question), trim($search)) !== false) {
         // do something
    }
```

I want to find "a." in string but strpos() always returns false OR not execute if statements. I could not understand how it's possible? Because my string contains "a." value.

I really appreciate for your answer.
Thank you all in advance.

Comment: why do you think it does not work? =  https://eval.in/620516

Comment: Are you sure that the `.` really is a `.` and not a character that looks like a `.` but isn't?

Comment: It works just fine. I copied and pasted your code: https://3v4l.org/sPdkd

Comment: Your code works is fine... This is a complete listing? Can copy and check again :)

Comment: it should work as it worked at my end

Comment: Your code works on PHP 7.0.2, 5.3.10, and 4.4.9 at http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/  so your issue is "in another castle"

Comment: Maybe problem a coding text or config php? Please try mb_strpos.... And write your version php, and php -i

Comment: Thank you all. Actually $question value is come from .docx file and in loop when I assign static value in variable then it's work..... how it possible?